# NSString dataUsingEncoding not encoding escaped quotes

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have an iOS application attempting to make a post request to the a rails server. The set body of the request method looks like this.

```
- (void)setBody:(NSString *)body{
    requestString = body;
    NSLog(@"request string: %@",requestString);
    [request setHTTPBody:[requestString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}
```

When I check the request string in the log, I see it outputted correctly as:

```
{"commit":"Create Order","order":{"price":"1","street_address":"(null)","state":"(null)","country":"USA","city":"(null)","zipcode":"(null)"}}
```

However, when the data reaches my web application, I am getting it with the original unescaped quotes.

```
Parameters: {"{\"commit\":\"Create Order\",\"order\":{\"price\":\"1\",\"street_address\":\"(null)\",\"state\":\"(null)\",\"country\":\"USA\",\"city\":\"it\",\"zipcode\":\"(null)\"}}"=>nil}
```

I doubt it is a Rails problem although it might be a possibility.

Any suggestions?

The original string is declared elsewhere as

```
NSString *order = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"commit\":\"Create Order\",\"order\":{\"price\":\"%@\",\"street_address\":\"%@\",\"state\":\"%@\",\"country\":\"%@\",\"city\":\"%@\",\"zipcode\":\"%@\"}}",@"1",streetAddressFieldText,stateFieldText,@"USA",cityFieldText,zipFieldText];
```

Comment: Are you sure your web service expects a single JSON dictionary as the data, and not say an array of dictionaries? Whats interesting about the string you print out - the "Parameters" is that its treating the string you upload as the key to a value that is missing (so its NULL). The quote after the '{' is just making a single string out of all you added as the body.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. The issue was actually server side with rails. I didn't declare the content type, and doing so fixed the issue.

```
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
```

Adding this before the request was executed caused Rails to correctly identify the escaped json.